# How can I catch soap messages on WCF Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a wcf web services. I am logging errors on db. My error log table has fields like ErrorMessage, Date, LogLevel, etc. I need to log also soap messages. How can I catch response and request soap messages inside my service?

EDIT: I am using log4net library for logging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869237/logging-wcf-request-to-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to  intercept all requests and responses in a reliable way  you have to implement [`BehaviorExtensionElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.behaviorextensionelement(v=vs.110).aspx) I have answered on how to implement it in this [`thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806555/how-to-put-inspector-on-both-client-and-server-wcf/22807535#22807535)

all  what you  can do is something like this

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
 {

       //here you can  create a buffered message as the original message can accessed only once 
           //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings);





            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue);
            //Create a copy of the message in order to continue the handling of te SOAP                 
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();
           request.WriteMessage(writer);
          //Recreate the message 
             writer.Flush();
            //Flush the contents of the writer so that the stream gets updated
             //you can log the str to the database 
            var str =  sw.ToString();

            request = buffer.CreateMessage();


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to “catch” and log the application messages at the “outermost” edge of your WCF service, then you should consider implementing an `IDispatchMessageInspector` which will enable custom inspection of inbound/outbound service messages.

The following MSDN link provides an overview of the `IDispatchMessageInspector`, which references your scenario:

> Implement IDispatchMessageInspector to inspect or modify inbound or
>   outbound application messages either prior to dispatching a request
>   message to an operation or before returning a reply message to a
>   caller. There are a large number of scenarios that require
>   intercepting messages prior to invoking the operation for which it is
>   destined. For example, you can log incoming application messages or
>   perform some feature based on a message header.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternatively, you could consider leveraging WCF Trace Logging with a custom database trace listener.  In that way, to WCF will feed the trace data to the custom listener, which can insert into the database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you have to combine ASP.NET system diagnostic components and log4net, by creating your own listener that will use log4net manager.

In your web config, have a look at `<system.diagnostics>` section and `<sharedListeners>`. In my case we are logging the full request/response into a file.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="d:\soap.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```